# Why doesn't drush check for updates of dev versions of my modules installed by composer?

Tags: drush, composer

I am using Drush (8.0.3) on my Drupal 8 site (8.0.3) to check for updates, but **Drush is not checking for updates of any modules that I checked out the dev branch for.**

```
$ drush @mysite ups --check-disabled 
Checking available update data for Drupal.                                  [ok]
Checking available update data for Address (address).                       [ok]
Checking available update data for CloudFlare (cloudflare).                 [ok]
Checking available update data for Commerce (commerce).                     [ok]
Checking available update data for Composer Manager                         [ok]
(composer_manager).
Checking available update data for Chaos tools (ctools).                    [ok]
Checking available update data for Domain Registration                      [ok]
(domain_registration).
Checking available update data for Entity (entity).                         [ok]
Checking available update data for Google Analytics                         [ok]
(google_analytics).
```

I have dev branches of the following modules:

- Inmail
- SMTP
- Rules
- Several others not in the list above

Now I have some idea about what may be wrong: I am using Pantheon for my site, and I added these modules to `composer.json`, then ran `composer update` to install them.  For dev modules, this adds `.git` repositories for each dev module.

I then committed all this to Pantheon, which gave me a message about not supporting submodules.  I ignored this message because I could still install the modules on Pantheon, but I now suspect that either this or installing via composer has somehow busted Drush for me.

How can I get Drush to also check for updates to the dev branches of modules installed by composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush relies on information written by the Drupal.org package manager to determine whether or not updates are needed to modules or core.

If you use `git` to install Drupal modules, then you may also use the [git-deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/git_deploy) module, and it will add the information needed for Drush to do the update.  Git deploy also works for modules installed via Composer using git; Composer uses git to install when using the --prefer-source directive, or when the module version installed is a development version.

If you use the Composer option --prefer-dist, then Composer will install the tarball packaged by drupal.org, which is why git-deploy is not needed in most cases for stable modules.

Note that there is a bug in git-deploy that prevents it from working when the path to the Drupal root contains spaces. There is a patch to fix this problem available in the git-deploy issue queue; see [#2672166](https://www.drupal.org/node/2672166).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Composer, why do you even need to use Drush to check for updates?  You can just run `composer update` and it will automatically pull updates in.

(This is not the definitive answer, but it occurs to me I could take this approach since I only update modules from my local dev machine anyway.)

Comment: It is useful to use Drush to check for updates even when using composer because `drush pm-updatestatus` produces a nice report that identifies security updates from non-security updates. Composer is lacking this feature.